# How to connect android phone internet with ubuntu

Tags: wireless

I am really disappointed..i have a rooted android phone(4.1) and ubuntu 12.04 laptop.My phone has  internet and i wanted to connect it to laptop via wifi(not usb tethering).i have searched a lot ,finding no right answer..please help.

Comment: Please add some details on what you have tried and what isn't working. If you want to connect your phone to your laptop through wi-fi without using a router, this is called using an "adhoc network", you might want to try searching for that. (Oh, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!)

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Systemsettings* and find the *Networks* section, click on the *more* and choose *tethering and mobile Hotspot* now choose *mobile Hotspot*
Configure it by clicking *configure WiFi Hotspot* and enable it.
Now go to Ubuntu select the WiFi, type in your Password and its done